# No rule to make target *.so

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-errors, qt4

I am trying to build this https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2 with ROS catkin. However, that shouldn't be that relevant. The error I am getting is with my installation of qt4.

No rule to make target `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQtGui.so', needed by`/home/odroid/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rgbdslam/rgbdslam'.  Stop.

I heard else where that this is caused by duplicate library files, but when I do

```
ldconfig -p | grep libQtGui
```

I get

```
libQtGui.so.4 (libc6,hard-float) => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQtGui.so.4
libQtGui.so (libc6,hard-float) => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQtGui.so
```

How would I fix this build error? I think it has something to do with RGBDSLAM not being designed for arm and searching in the wrong place, but it is only doing a find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED) and include(${QT_USE_FILE})

Edit: Another example:
No rule to make target `/usr/lib/libpcl_io.so', needed by`/home/odroid/catkin_ws/devel/lib/pcl_ros/convert_pcd_to_image'

I compiled both qt4 and pcl from source and only did sudo make install.

Comment: My makefu is weak, but I think you should be grepping for %.so to look for a  .so building rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that a second copy of the library is lying around. Run aptitude search  to find the extra copy.